# Error when subscribing to ERC-20 (BAT, i.e. Basic Attention Token)

Tags: ethereum, web3js, erc20

I'm trying to subscribe to BAT(Basic Attention Token) ERC-20 token "Transfer" event to detect any transaction made to my ethereum address using web3 in nodejs. I'm using parity (Parity/v1.10.6-stable-bc0d134-20180605/x86_64-linux-gnu/rustc1.26.1) node running on same local machine -

parity --jsonrpc-hosts all --jsonrpc-apis all --ws-apis all --ws-hosts all --ws-origins all --ws-interface all

Here is the code that I've used to subscribe -

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const abi = require('human-standard-token-abi');

var contract = '0x0D8775F648430679A709E98d2b0Cb6250d2887EF'; //BAT contract address

var web3Socket = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:8546'));

function tokenEventListener = (address) => {
        let token = new web3Socket.eth.Contract(abi, address);

        console.log(address);
        let subscription = token.events.Transfer({
            fromBlock: 0
        })
            .on('data', (event) => {
                 // do something
             })
            .on('error', console.error);
}

tokenEventListener(contract);
```

I get an error when I run the code -
 Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node on WS

Answer (score 0):

It means that your node is not set up properly. Change:

```
var web3Socket = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('ws://localhost:8546'));
```

to

```
var web3Socket = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws'));
```

This will connect to the Infura node which doesn't require you to host one.

Comment: @dkpaul91 if this answer was correct, please mark it as correct so future readers know this has been solved.